# Disappearing interfaces in ifconfig after docker run, unable to run container

Tags: docker, ifconfig

Trying to run container but it causes `ifconfig` disappearing interfaces, then unable to bind them to `docker0`

**Linux version:**

```
Linux 5.19.0-29-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jan 4 12:14:09 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:        22.10
Codename:       kinetic
```

**1. check ifconfig before run container:**

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:aa:3b:be:14  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2823  bytes 238614 (238.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2823  bytes 238614 (238.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:c1:5d:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.39.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.39.255
        ether 52:54:00:4e:11:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6d4e:a07b:411f:5ff1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:2b:e9:b5:42:30  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 196797  bytes 240397351 (240.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 54  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50394  bytes 9701876 (9.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**2. Run docker container:**

```
docker run hello-world                                                                                                                                                                              Thu 02 Feb 2023 12:01:42 PM CET

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

Everything's ok until 2nd run

**3. Second docker run**

```
docker run hello-world                                                                                                                                                                     1718ms  Thu 02 Feb 2023 12:03:40 PM CET
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint vigilant_haslett on network bridge: adding interface veth0c10d54 to bridge docker0 failed: could not find bridge docker0: route ip+net: no such network interface.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled 
4. Check ifconfig

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2936  bytes 249701 (249.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2936  bytes 249701 (249.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6d4e:a07b:411f:5ff1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:2b:e9:b5:42:30  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 257866  bytes 316947762 (316.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 76  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62581  bytes 11411451 (11.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
Disappeared docker0 and other interface and unable to bind any other container. Mostly it can't bridge any interface to erased docker0.
```

**Result of [check-config.sh](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh)**

```
sh ./check-config.sh                                                                                                                                                                                Thu 02 Feb 2023 12:11:13 PM CET
warning: /proc/config.gz does not exist, searching other paths for kernel config ...
info: reading kernel config from /boot/config-5.19.0-29-generic ...

Generally Necessary:
- cgroup hierarchy: properly mounted [/sys/fs/cgroup]
- apparmor: enabled and tools installed
- CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
- CONFIG_KEYS: enabled
- CONFIG_VETH: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_BRIDGE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MARK: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF: enabled

Optional Features:
- CONFIG_USER_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_SECCOMP: enabled
- CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP: enabled
    (cgroup swap accounting is currently enabled)
- CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP: enabled
- CONFIG_BLK_DEV_THROTTLING: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_PRIO: enabled
- CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH: enabled
- CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing
- CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_VS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_VS_NFCT: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_TCP: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_UDP: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_RR: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX: enabled
- CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR: enabled
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS: enabled
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL: enabled
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS_SECURITY: enabled
- Network Drivers:
  - "overlay":
    - CONFIG_VXLAN: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_BRIDGE_VLAN_FILTERING: enabled
      Optional (for encrypted networks):
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO: enabled
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO_AEAD: enabled
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO_GCM: enabled
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO_SEQIV: enabled
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO_GHASH: enabled
      - CONFIG_XFRM: enabled
      - CONFIG_XFRM_USER: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_XFRM_ALGO: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_INET_ESP: enabled (as module)
  - "ipvlan":
    - CONFIG_IPVLAN: enabled (as module)
  - "macvlan":
    - CONFIG_MACVLAN: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_DUMMY: enabled (as module)
  - "ftp,tftp client in container":
    - CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP: enabled (as module)
- Storage Drivers:
  - "aufs":
    - CONFIG_AUFS_FS: missing
  - "btrfs":
    - CONFIG_BTRFS_FS: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_POSIX_ACL: enabled
  - "devicemapper":
    - CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM: enabled
    - CONFIG_DM_THIN_PROVISIONING: enabled (as module)
  - "overlay":
    - CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS: enabled (as module)
  - "zfs":
    - /dev/zfs: present
    - zfs command: missing
    - zpool command: missing

Limits:
- /proc/sys/kernel/keys/root_maxkeys: 1000000
```

Do you have any ideas what may cause it, probably there's' some misconfiguration in the system.

Tried [this solution](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/312) by adding interface to `/etc/network/interfaces`, didn't work.